# How to get index of clicked element in Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

how to get index of element in Mootools like in jQuery.
For example:

```
    this.controls.addEvent('click', function(event){
        if (this.hasClass('h-inactiveslideshowcontrol')) {
            alert(this.index);
        }
    });
```

How to get index of clicked element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop through the element collection first.

```
this.controls.each(function(element, index){
    element.addEvent('click', function(event){
        if (this.hasClass('h-inactiveslideshowcontrol')) {
            alert(index);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: he can also do `this.controls.indexOf(this);` - particularly if delegation is used

Comment: Ha, nice, actually didn't knew this one.