# how can i get which nth-child event click with mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools-events

For example, I have fallowing code:

```
<ul id="agregator-menu">
    <li class="agregator-menu-item"><a href="">News</a></li>
    <li class="agregator-menu-item"><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
    <li class="agregator-menu-item"><a href="">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is here any way how i can get nth-child (1 or 2 or 3) with Mootools in click event?

EDIT: 
I apologize for the wrong question. May be this code help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var items = $$('.agregator-menu-item a');
    (items).addEvent('click', function(event) {
        /*here how i can get number of position agregator-menu-item (this) in 
          #agregator-menu  which user clicked 
        */      
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `document.getElements('#agregator-menu .agregator-menu-item")[1]` or nth-child etc - all should work.

Comment: so `document.getElement('#agregator-menu li:nth-child(1)')` gives you exactly 1 element

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get index of clicked element in Mootools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123650/how-to-get-index-of-clicked-element-in-mootools)

Comment: @Lukas, after your edit I think the linked answer solves your question. If not, comment here and you will get help.

Comment: why do you care which one it is? you get a reference to the element clicked itself (`this` in the function). you can get the text via `this.get('text')` or any other element attribute. there is no need to walk a collection of elements or to store a static index to get to it. if you MUST do it, you can do `items.indexOf(this)` -> index in Collection of `a` elements. looking at comment though, items is `a` and you want which `agregator-menu-item` it belongs to. that's slightly different but with this particular DOM, they will match as indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following code (also on http://jsfiddle.net/6p5y8vbn/)

HTML:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
    <button>Button 4</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var btns = $('buttons').getElements('button');

Array.each(btns, function(btn) {
    btn.addEvent('click', function() {
        console.log(btns.indexOf(this));
    });
});
```

`btns.indexOf(this)` will show you what the index of the clicked item in the array of buttons is. 
Note that Array indexes start at 0, so the first button clicked will return 0, second button 1 etc

Answer (score 0):

I want display `contentitems` with same index as `menuitems` onClick

result:

```
var menuitems = $$('.agregator-menu-item a');
var contentitems = $$('.agregator-item');

(menuitems).each( function(el, index) {
    el.addEvent('click', function(event) {
        event.stop();
        event.stopPropagation();
        contentitems.setStyle('display', 'none');
        contentitems[index].setStyle('display', 'block');   
    });
});
```